# site breaking in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am working on a website and I was (idiotically) only checking in Chrome and Firefox and when I pulled it up in IE it breaks, on a few different levels.

The top header colors wont show up and instead of stacking next to each other, two of the divs stack on top. The list for the slider also breaks.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Simple solution: "This site does not support IE".

Comment: Make sure your html is valid first: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.connorreaumond.com%2facacia2%2findex.html

Comment: Too many thoughts. thoughts<b>overflow</b>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in to declare doc type, etc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

-Your Brother Eric

Comment: Also use the HTML validator zippy linked you to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to validate html.
And always use Doctype because IE use Quirks mode